# Finding the intersections between $f(x)=ln(x)$ and $g(x)=0.1x$

Tags: calculus

$f(x)=ln(x)$

$g(x)=0.1x$

I have to prove whether if the following sentence is true or false:

> The graphs of the functions $g$ and $f$ intersect in only one point.

I can easily check that it is false by putting the functions on my calculator and looking at the graphs, however I want to try to do it analytically, so I tried:

$$ln(x) = 0.1x \Leftrightarrow e^{0.1x} = x \Leftrightarrow \sqrt[10]{e^x} = x \Leftrightarrow ???$$

What do I do next? Am I doing it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Is false, If $$F(x)=\ln{x}-0.1x$$

$F(1)=-0.1<0$,

$F(e)=1-0.1e=\frac{10-e}{10}>0\implies\exists x_0\in(1,e)$ with $F(x_0)=0$

$F(e^3)=\frac{30-e^3}{10}>0$

$F(e^{10})=\frac{100-e^{10}}{10}<0\implies\exists x_1\in(e^3,e^{10})$ with $F(x_1)=0$

Answer (score 0):

When you cannot get to a conclusion by numerically calculating the intersection points, and given that you are working with continuous functions, consider working with their derivatives and/or any other theorems that show the existance of 0s for the following function:

If $f = g $ for some point, then $f - g = 0$. You can show that there exists a 0 of a continuous function $h $ if you can find $a $ and $b $ such that $h(a)h(b) \le 0$. If you make $h = f - g $ you might get something useful for good values of $a $ and $b $. You can also try to study the function $f - g $ by taking into account its derivative, and then try to understand if it is true or not that $f = g $ for (more than) one point.

Answer (score 0):

Take $h(x)=g(x)-f(x)=0.1x - \ln(x)$

$lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}h(x)=lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x\left(0.1-\frac{\ln x}{x}\right)=\infty\cdot 0.1=\infty$

$lim_{n\rightarrow0^+}h(x)=0-(-\infty)=\infty$

$h(e)=0.1e-\ln(e)=0.2717...-1<0$

So $h$ is positive for $x$ large enough and positive small enough values of $x$, and $h(e)<0$. Also $h$ is continuous

By Intermediate Value Theorem $h$ has at least two roots.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the more general case of function $$f(x)=\log(x)-ax\implies f'(x)=\frac 1 x-a\implies f''(x)=\frac {-1}{x^2}$$ The first derivative cancels at $x=x_*=\frac 1a$ and the second derivative test shows that $x_*$ corresponds to a minimum.

So, if $$f(x_*)=-\log(a)-1$$ is positive, there is no intesection of the two curves. If it is $0$ (this is to say $a=\frac 1e$, there is only one root. If it is negative, corresponding to $a\lt\frac 1e$, there will be two roots.

You will learn, sooner or later, about the explicit solutions of $f(x)=0$.

For $a=0.1$, graphing the function, you would find roots around $x=1$ and $x=36$.